# How to store a condition as a string in node property or relationship property and use it in a query?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

```
create (bird:Class {name:'bird'})-[:isSubClassOf]->(animal:Class {name:'animal'})
create (animal)-[:hasOrgan {condition:'Exists (({x})-[:isInstanceOf]->(bird))'}]->(wing:organ {name:'wing'})
create (x:bird:instance {name:'pigeon_1'})-[:isInstanceOf]->(bird)
```

How to create a query to read the value of the condition expression and decide whether to create (pigeon_1)-[:hasOrgan]->(:wing) based on its value
MATCH (bird:Class {name:'bird'})-[:isSubClassOf]->(animal:Class {name:'animal'})

I created the following query but got an error, how should I fix it?

```
MATCH (animal)-[hasOrgan:hasOrgan]->(wing:organ)
WHERE hasOrgan.condition IS NOT NULL
WITH x, hasOrgan, wing, hasOrgan.condition AS condition
CALL apoc.cypher.doIt('RETURN ' + condition + ' AS value', {x: x, wing: wing})
YIELD value
WITH x, hasOrgan, wing, value AS conditionValue
WHERE conditionValue
CREATE (x)-[:hasOrgan]->(wing)
```

Comment: You cannot fix it. This part "WHERE conditionValue" will not work because it cannot interpret what conditionValue means.  You can create a query builder from python or java to write the dynamic query then run that query in neo4j.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query may work for you. It assumes that you first change your data model to replace the very complex relationship pattern `[:hasOrgan {condition:'Exists (({x})-[:isInstanceOf]->(bird))'}]` with the much simpler `[:hasOrgan {ifClass: 'bird'}]`.

```
MATCH (cls:Class)-[hasOrgan:hasOrgan]->(organ:organ)
WHERE hasOrgan.ifClass IS NOT NULL
MATCH p=(inst:instance)-[:isInstanceOf]->()-[:isSubClassOf*0..]->(cls)-[:isSubClassOf*0..]->(clsN)
WHERE
  NOT (clsN)-[:isSubClassOf]->() AND
  ANY(c IN TAIL(NODES(p)) WHERE hasOrgan.ifClass = c.name)
MERGE (inst)-[:hasOrgan]->(organ)
```

The query does this, in order:

1. Find each `hasOrgan` relationship having the `ifClass` property and the associated class `cls` and organ `organ`.
2. Find all the classes of each `instance` that is (directly or indirectly) in the class `cls`, and filter out an instance if it does not belong to the class specified by `hasOrgan.ifClass`.
3. Use `MERGE` to create the `hasOrgan` relationship, if it does not already exist.